# How to restore a file from another git repo

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, server

I have a project uploaded to the server and I deleted one of the project files by mistake, now the project is connected to the git and I want to restore the file that I deleted from the copy of the project on the local, what do I do?

I tried to make "git pull", but I got "Already up to date."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have not staged the deletion yet, simply run `git restore <filename>` and the file will be restored from the index.